# Making a full height and width menu bar when pressing on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I want to when I press a menu button on the top right, something slides from the left to the right full screen (full height and width) and everything else vanishes.
The problem here is that if you scroll down then click the menu button it doesn't show it only shows on the top.
Plus there's something I don't quite understand, the height and the width. If i want something to cover the whole page or only the height and width that is visible to us how do we do something like that ? For this I put 100% height and width so it's the visible part of the page, what if we want the whole page to be covered in something ?
How does the height and width work?

```js
$("#side-button").click(function(){
  if ($("#side-bar").css("display") == "block"){
    $("body").css("overflow","auto");
    $("#side-bar").animate({width: "0%"},400,function(){
        $("#side-bar").css("display","none");
    });
  }
  else{
    $("#side-bar").css("display","block").animate({width: "100%"},400,function(){
      $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
html{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
body{
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#side-bar{
  position: absolute;
  width:0%;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  display:none;
}

#side-button{
  display:flex;
  position:fixed;
  right:10px;
  top:10px;
  z-index: 100;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#side-button div{
  width:100%;
  height:4px;
  background-color: gray;
  display:block;
}

#side-button:hover #first{
  transform: rotate(1turn);
  transition: 1s transform;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="side-bar">
    <div class="page-header text-center header1">
      <h1>THIS IS A HEADER</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="side-button" >
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
  </div>
<div class="container" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
  <div class="jumbotron ">
    <h1>This is a jumbotron !</h1>
    <p>The jumbotron makes a big fat div :p </p>
  </div>
    <div class="jumbotron ">
    <h1>This is a jumbotron !</h1>
    <p>The jumbotron makes a big fat div :p </p>
  </div>
    <div class="jumbotron ">
    <h1>This is a jumbotron !</h1>
    <p>The jumbotron makes a big fat div :p </p>
  </div>
    <div class="jumbotron ">
    <h1>This is a jumbotron !</h1>
    <p>The jumbotron makes a big fat div :p </p>
  </div>
  </div>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it changing the position absolute from the side bar to fixed, the position will be relative to the viewport and will be fixed at the top

```js
$("#side-button").click(function(){
  if ($("#side-bar").css("display") == "block"){
    $("body").css("overflow","auto");
    $("#side-bar").animate({width: "0%"},400,function(){
        $("#side-bar").css("display","none");
    });
  }
  else{
    $("#side-bar").css("display","block").animate({width: "100%"},400,function(){
      $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
html{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
body{
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#side-bar{
  position: fixed;
top: 0;
  width:0%;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  display:none;
}

#side-button{
  display:flex;
  position:fixed;
  right:10px;
  top:10px;
  z-index: 100;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#side-button div{
  width:100%;
  height:4px;
  background-color: gray;
  display:block;
}

#side-button:hover #first{
  transform: rotate(1turn);
  transition: 1s transform;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="side-bar">
    <div class="page-header text-center header1">
      <h1>THIS IS A HEADER</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="side-button" >
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
  </div>
<div class="container" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
  <div class="jumbotron ">
    <h1>This is a jumbotron !</h1>
    <p>The jumbotron makes a big fat div :p </p>
  </div>
    <div class="jumbotron ">
    <h1>This is a jumbotron !</h1>
    <p>The jumbotron makes a big fat div :p </p>
  </div>
    <div class="jumbotron ">
    <h1>This is a jumbotron !</h1>
    <p>The jumbotron makes a big fat div :p </p>
  </div>
    <div class="jumbotron ">
    <h1>This is a jumbotron !</h1>
    <p>The jumbotron makes a big fat div :p </p>
  </div>
  </div>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: YES ! thankyou so much, and can you explain the part about the width and the height? if i want something to be 100% of the height of the full page and if i want it to be 100% of the height of the visible part of the page, how do we do that how does width and height work in css

Answer (score 0):

The side bar has a absolute position, which still refers to the document.

So you want to take `#side-bar` outside of the document flow by placing it `fixed`.
It will then be "above" the viewport.

I than use top, left, bottom and width to animate it.

```js
$("#side-button").click(function(){
  if ($("#side-bar").css("display") == "block"){
    $("body").css("overflow","auto");
    $("#side-bar").animate({left: "-100%"},400,function(){
        $("#side-bar").css("display","none");
    });
  }
  else{
    $("#side-bar").css("display","block").animate({left: "0%"},400,function(){
      $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
html{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
body{
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#side-bar{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:-100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  z-index: 100;
  display:none;
}

#side-button{
  display:flex;
  position:fixed;
  right:10px;
  top:10px;
  z-index: 100;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#side-button div{
  width:100%;
  height:4px;
  background-color: gray;
  display:block;
}

#side-button:hover #first{
  transform: rotate(1turn);
  transition: 1s transform;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="side-bar">
    <div class="page-header text-center header1">
      <h1>THIS IS A HEADER</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="side-button" >
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
  </div>
<div class="container" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
  <div class="jumbotron ">
    <h1>This is a jumbotron !</h1>
    <p>The jumbotron makes a big fat div :p </p>
  </div>
    <div class="jumbotron ">
    <h1>This is a jumbotron !</h1>
    <p>The jumbotron makes a big fat div :p </p>
  </div>
    <div class="jumbotron ">
    <h1>This is a jumbotron !</h1>
    <p>The jumbotron makes a big fat div :p </p>
  </div>
    <div class="jumbotron ">
    <h1>This is a jumbotron !</h1>
    <p>The jumbotron makes a big fat div :p </p>
  </div>
  </div>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```